# Scanning QR Code via mobile cam in a web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, qr-code

I'm building a web app using **ruby on rails** and i want the user to click on button that opens 
the camera and scans a QR code then send the content of the code automatically to the server.

is there a Gem to help me with this or a block of JS code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this reliably with pure HTML + JS currently. Availability of camera API is not guaranteed on all of your client browsers. Currently it is available only on mobile versions of the Firefox and Chrome browsers : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/Camera

You will have to use a flash component. But a flash based solution is not guaranteed to work on all mobiles.

Nevertheless, a quick google search lead me to this : http://headshot.hypermediasoft.com/ (Never used it though).

You can follow the development of Device APIs in the browsers here : http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/

Comment: This is great , but in addition to opening the cam , i need to scan a QR code , that's the main problem.